# Paypal Express Checkout- reactivate suspended profile and balance

Tags: express, paypal, checkout, recurring-billing

In sandbox I created a recurring profile with MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS set to 1 so if a payment fails the profile will be suspended(I check the profile of the profileId of paypal saved in db so if the status of paypal isn't 'Active' I know that there is something wrong'...

But when a customer wants to reactivate his profile I can't find anywhere in paypal documentation what happened... Let's say my customer has is profile suspended in 2015/01/24 and in 2015/03/13 he wants to reactivate the profile... Me I just to want that his new monthly payment cycle begin this date (2015/03/13) and don't care about outstanding balance and what he must has owed between these dates...

The question is I don't know if when profile is suspended if the interval between suspension and reactiviton the amount due to each cycle is added to the outsanding balance (I want that it's not the case) and if yes how can I change this behaviour?

Comment: Read the docs for a more reliable answer (I'm not certain), but I believe you cannot reactivate a recurring payment profile; you usually just set up a new one.

Comment: You can reactivayr via ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus a suspended profile...I just don't know what happens with balance issue and billing date...I can't find nowhere in paypal website

Comment: Best suggestion then is to test it out on sandbox and see.

Comment: The problem is that I can suspend a profile easily...but I don't knlw how simulate a failed payment...if I suspend a profile that will nlt answer my question because there will be no failed payments before I reactivate the profile...but I want to know for the balance when there has been a failed payment before the profile is suspended

Comment: Go into the buyer account & remove all the funding sources (and balances). The next payment will fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a profile becomes suspended you cannot reactivate it unless it has an outstanding balance of $0.00.  You can use the [BillOutstandingAmount](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/BillOutstandingAmount_API_Operation_NVP/) API to do exactly that, and then you can reactivate the profile manually or via the [ManageCreateRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus_API_Operation_NVP/) API after that.

If you don't want to collect the balance then you'll need to set it to $0 manually or via the [UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/) API.  Then you could reactivate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following link to re-Activate an agreement again. 
[Re-Activate](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/#billing-agreements_reactivate).

PayPal has recently changed subscriptions from S- subscriptions to I- subscriptions.

The difference about I- subscriptions is that after a subscription payment fails, the subscription is suspended instead of canceled.